# Nuxeo Cluster - Load Balancer - Session replication failed

Tags: apache, session, nuxeo, sticky-session

I have configured apache2.4 http load balancer as :

```
ProxyPass /nuxeo balancer://sticky-balancer   stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=On

<Proxy balancer://sticky-balancer >
BalancerMember xxxxxxx.40:8080/nuxeo route=nxworker1
BalancerMember xxxxxxx.41:8080/nuxeo route=nxworker2
</Proxy >
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

On nuxeo instances I have done config as suggested on nuxeo docs at 40:
nuxeo.server.jvmRoute=nxworker1 and  nuxeo.server.jvmRoute=nxworker2 at 41

When one of instances goes down for ex 40, during a user is connected and working on it, it needed to do login again because session
seems is not replicated for node 41

Have any body any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: For the record, question was cross-posted at https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/f96029ea79354d2ebd3f33d211ce2021/Nuxeo-Cluster-Load-Balancer-Sess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected: the session is sticky, not replicated. As stated in the documentation, you will have to authenticate again or not, depending on your configuration and architecture:

> The Nuxeo Platform requires all calls to be authenticated. Depending on your architecture, authentication can be stateless (ex: Basic Auth) or stateful (ex: Form + Cookie). Either way, you probably don't want to replay authentication during all calls.
>
> That's why having a session based authentication + session affinity can make sense: you don't have to re-authenticate each time you call the server.
>
> If the session affinity can not be restored, for example because the target server has been shutdown:
>
> - stateless authentication will be automatically replayed (ex: Basic Auth)
> - for stateful authentication:
>
>   - if you have a SSO this will be transparent
>   - if you don't have a SSO, user will have to authenticate again.

Comment: Thanks Julien Carsique!